# JavaScript Rain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for someone to help me improve this code. It works great but can sometimes slow my browser down a lot when raindrops are at a high amount.

```
<section class="rain"></section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    background: #0D343A;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(13, 52, 58, 1)), to(#000000));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13, 52, 58, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .drop {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(13, 52, 58, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13, 52, 58, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .6) 100%);
    width: 1px;
    height: 89px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
  }
  /* animate the drops*/

  @-webkit-keyframes fall {
    to {
      margin-top: 900px;
    }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes fall {
    to {
      margin-top: 900px;
    }
  }
</style>
<script>
  // number of drops created.
  var nbDrop = 1000;

  // function to generate a random number range.
  function randRange(minNum, maxNum) {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
  }

  // function to generate drops
  function createRain() {

    for (i = 1; i < nbDrop; i++) {
      var dropLeft = randRange(0, 1600);
      var dropTop = randRange(-1000, 1400);

      $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop' + i + '"></div>');
      $('#drop' + i).css('left', dropLeft);
      $('#drop' + i).css('top', dropTop);
    }

  }
  // Make it rain
  createRain();
</script>
```

Comment: Here's [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/won0zjog/) of the OP's code.

Answer (score 6):

### Naming

*If you need comment to explain a variable then the variable is not named correctly.*

Variable `nbDrop` and functions `randRange` and `createRain` are accompanied with comments explaining their purpose. This is indication of non-descriptive names.
Instead of `nbDrop`, `numberOfDrops` is self-explanatory name and does not require comment explaining what the variable contains. Similarly, `randRange` can be renamed to `getRandomNumberInRange`. Although, the name is looking long, it's descriptive.

### Unnecessary Comments

Now, after changing the variables/functions name as shown in above section comment associated with them can be removed.

Below comments are unnecessary:

```
// Make it rain
createRain();
```

`createRain` is pretty expressive. Anyone reading code can infer by reading the function name that it must be creating rain. So, the comment is not required.

Or, in other words, you may rename the function to `makeRain` and then remove comment. Which one to choose depends on your taste.

### Globals

`nbDrop`, `randRange`, `createRain` are globals. While it doesn't affect when working on small projects, it'll interfere with other developers code when working with large projects in big team due to variable names collision. To solve this the code can be wrapped in IIFE. See [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Implicit Global

Variable `i` used in `for` is implicit global. It is not declared(no `var`, `let`, `const`) but used. See [Declaring variables without var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888570/declaring-variables-without-var-keyword)

### Better use of jQuery

```
    $('#drop' + i).css('left', dropLeft);
    $('#drop' + i).css('top', dropTop);
```

Using method chaining, above code can be written as

```
    $('#drop' + i).css('left', dropLeft)
        .css('top', dropTop);
```

Or better, [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) accepts object of styles(key-value pairs). Now, the code will become

```
$('#drop' + i).css({
    'left': dropLeft,
    'top': dropTop
});
```

---

> It works great but can sometimes slow my browser down a lot when raindrops are at a high amount.

Main reason behind this could be more number of *DOM dives*.

Each time `$(selector)` is used, jQuery has to *dive* into DOM, get the element and then perform operations on it. In the function `createRain` inside of `for`, three times DOM elements are referred(`$('.rain')` and `$('#drop' + i)` twice). This means, 3000 dives for 1000 rain drops.

The question is **Can we reduced these *dives*? And how much?**

**Yes.** We can reduce the *dives* by caching the elements. `$('.rain')` can be moved before the `for` and cached

```
var $rain = $('.rain');
for (i = 1; i < nbDrop; i++) {
```

Here, we've cached the element which can be referenced inside the loop. This will bring the *dives* to 2001(one for `.rain`, 2000 for `'#drop' + i`).

After chaining/using `css(properties)`, number of *dives* will become 1001.

**Can we reduce this further?**

**Yes.** Instead of applying styles after element is added to DOM, we can add styles to element and then throw it in DOM.

```
    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop' + i + '" style="left: ' + dropLeft + 'px; top: ' + dropTop +'px;"></div>');
```

Did this actually reduced the *DOM dives*? `append` is also a *dive*. But, this code help us realize that ID attribute on each `.drop` is just used to apply styles on it. If we use this syntax, we can remove ID of element.

Let's use old formula here:

```
Create a string.    
loop:
    append to string
end:
use string here.
```

Using this, *DOM dives* will reduced to **one**. *peace!*.

```
var rainDrops = '';
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrops; i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0, 1600);
    var dropTop = randRange(-1000, 1400);

    rainDrops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + dropLeft + 'px; top: ' + dropTop + 'px;"></div>';
}

$('.rain').append(rainDrops);
```

### Who needs jQuery?

Looking at above code, I realize jQuery is used only once to append the drops in container. *append*? The function is called only once, so we're not even actually appending(adding to existing content) them, we're setting(by setting I mean to add them and not append) them.

So, we can remove dependency on jQuery completely and use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select element

```
document.querySelector('.rain').innerHTML = rainDrops;
```

<sup>It's funny to put this right after above section</sup>

### Magic Numbers

`1600`, `1400` what are they?

Instead of using them directly, create a variable(of course with a descriptive name) and then use that variable.

We can infer them as screen width and screen height respectively. But how did you know my screen resolution? Or even, is that my screen resolution?

JavaScript provides a better way to get the width and height of browser. So, `1600` will become `window.innerWidth` and `1400` will become `window.innerHeight`.

### Configurable number of drops

By passing the `numberOfDrops` as argument to `createRain()` will give more control on how many drops to be shown. If nothing is passed, default `1000` can be used.

Enough of talking, show me the code now!

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function getRandomNumberInRange(minimum, maximum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
  }

  function createRain(numberOfDrops) {
    numberOfDrops = numberOfDrops || 1000;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var rainDrops = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrops; i++) {
      var dropLeft = getRandomNumberInRange(0, windowWidth);
      var dropTop = getRandomNumberInRange(-1000, windowHeight);

      rainDrops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + dropLeft + 'px; top: ' + dropTop + 'px;"></div>';
    }

    document.querySelector('.rain').innerHTML = rainDrops;
  }

  createRain(250);
}());
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #0D343A;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(13, 52, 58, 1)), to(#000000));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13, 52, 58, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drop {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(13, 52, 58, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13, 52, 58, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .6) 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 89px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
}


/* animate the drops*/

@-webkit-keyframes fall {
  to {
    margin-top: 900px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fall {
  to {
    margin-top: 900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="rain"></section>
```